Prevent Chrome from Changing Font Size
Consider the following piece of code. I have set the font size of the whole document to 16px. However, when I open this page on a Galaxy S9+, remote debugging reveals that the computed style for font size of the paragraph in the second section is 17.6px. It seems that -webkit-text-size-adjust: none does not work. I also used the proper meta tag for width.
I am using Chrome 127.0.6533.103 on android. Is there anyway to prevent chrome from font resizing in this situation?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Webpage</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html {
            height: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: black;
            background-color: whitesmoke;
        }

        section {
            background-color: lightgray;
            margin: 1rem 0;
            padding: 1rem 2rem;
        }

        .flex-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section>
            <div class="flex-container">
                <div>
                    <p>Some sample text in original font size.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum magni eligendi
                officia velit corporis dolorum reiciendis autem aperiam veniam, voluptatum illum 
                cum est. Accusamus deleniti numquam corporis mollitia libero tempora?
            </p>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>

Here is the output result.


Have you tried without the —webkit? Also what happens in a container set with narrower width?

@AHaworth: I also tried text-size-adjust: none to no avail. I tried putting the text into a container. Surprisingly, setting display: flex or display: inline-block for the container prevents chrome from resizing. The reason why the first section has the original font size is that it is a flex container! I do not understand why chrome does this! They should just leave such issues to the designer of the website.

Try text-size-adjust: 100%;.

@htor: That does not work neither!

I tried putting the text into a container. Surprisingly, setting display: flex or display: inline-block for the container prevents chrome from font resizing. The reason why the first section has the original font size is that it is a flex container! I do not understand why chrome does this! They should just leave such issues to the designer of the website. This hack also works by setting max-height: 1000000px in a reset setting or for the container. Here is a modified version of the above code.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Webpage</title>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html {
            height: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: black;
            background-color: whitesmoke;
        }

        section {
            background-color: lightgray;
            margin: 1rem 0;
            padding: 1rem 2rem;
        }

        .flex-container {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .section-content {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <section>
            <div class="flex-container">
                <div>
                    <p>Some sample text in original font size.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div class="section-content">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum magni eligendi
                    officia velit corporis dolorum reiciendis autem aperiam veniam, voluptatum illum 
                    cum est. Accusamus deleniti numquam corporis mollitia libero tempora?
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>

and the output is

